# Morphism of projective varieties defined locally

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing

Let $X$ be a projective variety and $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be a covering of $X$ of locally closed irriducible subsets (quasi-projective subvarieties of $X$). I'm trying to check that if $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ is a map of projective varieties such that $f_{|U_i}\colon U_i\longrightarrow Y$ is a morphism then $f$ is morphism. Any help?

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Comment: I hope it's true! I'm reading this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.8725&rep=rep1&type=pdf . First the author proves the Theorem 2.2. then says that by this follows that  the map $C_r(X,i*j)\longrightarrow C_r(X,i)$ is algebraic. I think that the algebricity of this map follows by the fact that the gdc realizes a morphism from an irreducible component of $C_r(X,i*j)$ to one of  $C_r(X,i)$, as said in the paper cited here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781147/morphism-of-varieties-defined-by-the-greatest-common-divisor/2781959#2781959

Comment: Consider the map from $\mathbb{P}^1=\mathbb{A}^1\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself given by identity on $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\infty\mapsto 0\in\mathbb{A}^1$. The two sets are locally closed (one is open and the other closed). The map restricted to these sets is clearly morphisms, but the whole map is certainly not.